# Making data.table sparse with NAs

Tags: r, data.table, sparse-matrix

I thought it could be useful to maintain maximum number of NAs in my dataset (they constitute above 80% of values), but it seems that containing them doesn't reduce size of data.table object, could I reduce size of data.table object with many NAs (without turning it into sparse matrix with Matrix library) ?

Comment: see `object.size(NA)`, `object.size(TRUE)`, `object.size(NA_real_)`, `object.size(1)`, etc

Comment: `data.table` doesn't really have a concept of _true_ "sparsity"; `Matrix` is indeed the way to go here.